# Make an image responsive inside a relative positioned container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make a really simple slideshow with images appearing from right to left as animation:

```js
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');
let l = slides.length;
let i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
i = (i + 1) % l;
 if(i == 0){
  for(let j = l - 1;j != 0;j--){
   slides[j].classList.remove('img-slide');
  }
 } else {
  slides[i].classList.add('img-slide');
 }
}, 3500);
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
}

.section-1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: calc(100vh - 104.5px);
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
}

.img-container {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 transition: ease 0.7s;
}

.img-container:nth-child(1){
 z-index: 0;
}

.img-container:nth-child(2){
 z-index: 1;
}

.img-container:nth-child(3){
 z-index: 2;
}

.img-container:nth-child(4){
 z-index: 3;
}

.img-container:nth-child(2).img-slide{
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.img-container:nth-child(3).img-slide{
 transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.img-container:nth-child(4).img-slide{
 transform: translateX(-300%);
}
```

```html
   <section class="section-1">
    <div class="img-container">
     <img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/PKffm2uI4dk/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
     <img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/PKffm2uI4dk/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
     <img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/PKffm2uI4dk/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
     <img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/PKffm2uI4dk/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>  
   </section>
```

Those images are just an example so of course they appear stretched.
The images that i have to use are four different png images 4000x4000 with transparency so "img-container" must be the 100% of the body and also have a background color. The section must have a fixed height. The result with those images is kinda awful they look  a bit stretched and on mobile some of those are cropped.
I tried to include

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

But the result was that all the four images became smaller and they all appeared simultaneously in the viewport. How can I fix that or where can I learn more about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to achieve that you can use  [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), `object-fit: cover`or `object-fit: contain` on the image tag

```
element.style {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that! On desktop works perfectly, but on mobile some of them are still cropped :/

Comment: Nvm just fixed it